# Gallery of good UITableView designs

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

UITableView has lots of customization options and lots of websites to explain each option. Is there a website that shows full circle designs that look nice and show how to do it? I am not interested in tutorials that are set up to illustrate how customization is done, I'm looking for a gallery that shows good designs that I can copy or start with.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I always recommend Cocoa Controls for these sorts of things

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=UITableView

Comment: Just tried, worked for me (was referred to https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=UITableView)